# I am facing an issue with deletion operation in Stored procedures(packages)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am facing an issue here. I have a table `Products` where there are columns called `prod_trkg_tran_id` and `cntr_nbr` etc. I also have two tables `instance1` and `instance2` which also contains `prod_trkg_tran_id` and `cntr_nbr` and they have one row of data each with same `cntr_nbr`. I ran a query like below in Oracle SQLDeveloper. It worked fine and deleted a row from `prod_trkg_tran`. Can you explain this??

But when i tried this in SP by assigning:

```
p_where_clause:=  'WHERE t.prod_trkg_tran_id in (
    select distinct tp82.PROD_TRKG_TAN_ID
    from instance_1 tp21
    join instance_2 tp82 on tp21.cntr_nbr=tp82.cntr_nbr
)'
```

and called a method `delete_table` which a statement contains

```
'DELETE FROM ' || p_table_name ||' t ' || p_where_clause;
```

`p_table_name` is `prod_trkg_tran` and `p_where_clause` is the one which I defined earlier.

If I run this, SP records are not getting deleted from `prod_trkg_tran`.

Ideally it was supposed to delete like I tried in SQLDeveloper. Can you explain this?

```
delete from prod_trkg_tran t 
WHERE t.prod_trkg_tran_id in (
    select distinct tp82.PROD_TRKG_TRAN_ID  
    from  instance_1 tp21 
    join instance_2 tp82 on tp21.cntr_nbr=tp82.cntr_nbr
);
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: Is there any error? If so, which one? Does that procedure have WHEN OTHERS exception handler? If so, remove it. Could you post the whole procedure you wrote, along with some sample data?

Comment: Are you commiting at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably a grant issue where executing schema/user does not have grant for delete or select aforamentioned tables.

If your user have DBA privileges you do not encounter with this error while using SQL Developer, however Stored Procedure does.

In your case, your tables may be synonyms to another schema table and you may not have grants on these tables.

Please make sure that you have sufficient grants.

By the way, what is the error that you are facing?

Comment: I am not getting error delete is not not happening, i.e tables contents remains same.